# Are functions which say $X$ onto $Y$ mean the function is surjective?

Tags: notation

Throughout my reading I've encountered theorems which use certain wording, which is unclear at times. For example, consider the following corollary taken out of Intro to Topology by Mendelson,

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous mapping of $X$ onto $Y$, and let $X$ be connected; then $Y$ is connected.

Does the fact that it's written "..mapping $X$ $\textbf{onto}$ $Y$" imply that the function $f$ is surjective, i.e., onto? I've also seen $X$ into $Y$ and I'm wondering if that means injective?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: I have never heard injectivity referred to as "into"

Comment: Okay, how about for onto? Does that ever mean the function itself is onto?

Comment: Sujaan, I accidentally deleted the comment you just made. Thank you for the answer, it helped clear things up.

Comment: @ShantDanielian From what I was reading at wikiproof, a function f that maps, as in your example, X **onto** Y is actually surjective. On the other hand, if the function is not surjective you write that f maps X **into** Y. Not gonna lie, I was actually blown away. The link to the article is this: [Wikiproof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Surjection)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a mapping of $X$ **onto** $Y$ is a surjection from $X$ onto $Y$.

When $f$ is described as a function from $X$ **into** $Y$, you **cannot** infer that it is injective. Usually it just means that $f:X\to Y$, i.e., that $Y$ is the codomain of $f$. Once in a great while you might see it used to mean that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ that is **not** surjective, but if that’s what the author intends, it should be made explicit.

Comment: Ah! I'm such a slow-writer! =)

Comment: Great to know, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Shant: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you drop by the chat?